# how to get callback for scriptaculous autocomplete

Tags: jsp, prototypejs, scriptaculous

In my jsp file i have a search text box and i'm trying to get the autosuggestion from my server jsp component into div using prototype and scriptaculous  library.

Below is the part in my jsp page

```
<%
String name = "objectName";
%>

<input autocomplete="off" name="<%=name%>" size="60" type="text" value="" />
<div class="auto_complete" id="object_name_auto_complete"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">new Ajax.Autocompleter('<%=name%>', 'object_name_auto_complete', '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/component/ajax_introdata', {})</script>
```

The request is sucessfully going to server and its printing results and then result is formatted as

```
<ul><li>suggestion-1</li></ul>
```

But the suggestions are not showing in client jsp text field. Just wondering how to check the status of the request from client jsp(either by using callback) for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

`Ajax.Automcompleter()` is looking for an element IDs not a element names - the div holder `object_name_auto_complete` is correct but you need to change

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="<%=name%>" size="60" type="text" value="" />
```

to

```
<input autocomplete="off" name="<%=name%>" id="<%=name%>" size="60" type="text" value="" />
```

Comment: Actually i'm getting the callback but its not displaying since the the div where the results were loading is present in one frame and another frame is present under it. Is it possible to display a div of one frame to another frame(z-index of frame and div)